# Why this bash shortcuts does not work?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a test script like this:

```
asdf() {
  return 1
}

asdf && echo 123 && exit
echo 321
```

321 is outputed instead of 123

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&&` operator is a logical AND.  It does lazy evaluation : if the statement to the left evaluates to `false` (i.e. non-zero return code), then applying the logical AND will still evaluate to `false` anyway, so evaluating the right part is useless (in the logical predicate sense).

Since your function returns 1 (`false` as far as Bash is concerned), everything to the right is ignored, your `exit` is not reached, and the `echo` statement is executed.

If you want to force execution of all commands on that line, use this instead:

```
{ asdf ; echo 123 ; exit ; }
```

A command list like this will always evaluate every one of them, irrespective of their return code.  Please note that the last semi-colon is mandatory.

Comment: Try not to use Boolean terminology when discussing exit statuses. `bash` *does* have a context where Boolean values are represented with true as 1 and false as 0, namely arithmetic expressions (try `echo $(( 3 < 5))`), so it's better to keep the concepts of truth and success distinct.

Answer (score 1):

`echo 123` will only be executed **iff** `asdf` succeeds as you have tacked the short circuit operator -- `&&` after `asdf`; now you have `return`-ed from the function `asdf` with return value 1, which in turn becomes the exit status of `asdf`, so the command `asdf` is considered failed, hence `echo 123` (and of course `exit`) is never run.

There is no such condition on `echo 321`, hence it is executed in the usual manner.